# Animated CopyLocation bone constraint delay problem

Tags: animation

I have set my rig with IK where I am trying to copy location of Bone of different armature (Sword) to my main IK bone (LeftHand) using Copy Location Constraint.

It works well but when it is animated there is always 1 frame delay at least it seems for me(maybe more). Means that target bone is 1 frame ahead compared to bone that copies the location. When I export animation via Fbx to UE4 the delay is clearly visible unless I change "Sampling Rate" 0.8 or less but then the exported animation contain a lot of unnecessary frames and exported file is a lot bigger... Thanks for any advice

[image: RigSetup]
[image]

Comment: You probably have a dependency loop.  Open a console window and look for "dependency cycle" warnings.  Fix them.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this problem is to bake animation of IK bone then move all baked keys 1 frame back and disable "copy Location" Constraint. Then the animation is perfectly smooth but it's very unpractical so when I change a little detail in animation, I have to rebake...